# How I can to add file in a SolutionFolder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates

I try to create a template for Visual Studio and I have a problem by adding file in `SolutionFolder`. This folder will have a follow named - `Solution Items`.  I try to add a file build.cake (it's not referring to any project and should be just in `Solution Items` in the solution root) but I don't know how I can do it.

So, I try to do it now

```
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
        <SolutionFolder Name="Solution Items">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="build.cake">build.cake</ProjectItem>
        </SolutionFolder>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
```

But it's not working

Comment: Did you use the vs template export tool ?

Comment: @GrégoryL Yes, I used that for projects, but it's not working for singular files

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a "_Readme" solution folder with couple of static txt files. I added <SolutionFolder Name="_Readme">???</SolutionFolder> but don't know what what to put in the element.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** :: According to what I read and tried, it's not possible with basics template tool offered by VS.

[Kind of old but maybe have a look here.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7407d60-96e3-429a-84ef-be4cb8edcf95/adding-solution-items-to-a-multiproject-template?forum=vsx)

---

---

Well, for my own template I had 5 projects in one solution,

I had to create a template with VS for each project of the solution
Then I had to create a .vstemplate file that linked everyproject.

(Which also need to edit every package path and rename projects name)

So maybe this way, you can create a project template, with root files, linked to subproject ?

My solution template procedure is the following :

1. Create each project template
2. Unzip them in a folder

So at this point I got a folder Template with one folder by project:

```
 Template/
     Template/
     Template.Models/
     Template.Emails/
```

3. Create a main vstemplate file

Here is mine, as an example : (Be careful with $projectname$ variable, they're defined according to the link between the vstemplate you're editing and the project you're pointing to)

[image]

4. Then in every project you have to :

   - in csproj files : Reference to another project of the solution must be replaced by correct generic name
   - in csproj files : Path to /packages folder start with ..\packages and must now be ....\packages
   - Do the same in each project vstemplate file
   - In every cs files where you have a using to another project fo the solution, you must also replace the name by the generic name.

This way I think that if you add a file in the main vstemplate file, you could add a file to the solution. I'll try to test if I can today.

**Note : Generic names**

Generic names you want to use instead of projects names must be used depending of the link between the file you're editing and the project you reference. Here is my chart to explain :

[image]

For instance, if I have a reference to Template.Models in the project Template (which is the main, webform project fo my solution) I use the link $safeprojectname$.Models

**Long story short**

Maybe you're trying to create a project template and want to create a solution from it. However here you need to create a project template for a solution. With a main vstemplate linked to every project of the solution. And this main vstemplate will contain the projectItem.